# Android Studio signs APK only when Build APK is chosen and not when Run button is clicked

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Android Studio signs an APK only when I go `Build/Build Bundles Apks/Build APK`. When the run button to automatically run it on the emulator is clicked the application is **not** signed. I have verified this by inspecting the application with `adb pull` from the emulator.

The following is the build gradle I have:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"


    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storeFile file('/home/pc/.android/debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        custom {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable true
        }
    }


}
```

I am choosing from the build variants the `custom` one I have created.

I havent touched this app for a while now but a similar project I had was working properly several months ago. Is there some update or something else that is causing this behavior? Am I missing something?

- Android Version 3.6.1
- Java Version = java-8-openjdk

  - I know the config is correct as the Build APK actually signs the APK
  - I know that the APK installed on the emulator when the button `run` is clicked does not contain the signature as i have inspected the META-INF directory of the apk. But i have also verified it by trying to print the signature programmatically.

According to [Android user guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/run) the run button should have the same result as the Build APK!

What could be the issue of the above and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent a considerable amount of time trying to solve this and I hope to save some time from anyone else facing this.

- Go to `Run`/`Edit Configurations`
- In the tab `General` in section `Installation Options`
- In Deploy choose `APK from app bundle`

[image: Image from Android Studio]